# Kafka Authorization between nodes with TLS

Tags: apache-kafka, acl, tls1.2

I am having a terrible time with authorization ACLs on Kafka 2.6. I have TLS setup and working fine between my client app and all kafka nodes. I have the acl properties in the server.properties file

```
#TLS Portion
advertised.listeners=SSL://10.1.1.2:9092
listeners=SSL://:9092
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/kafka/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2
ssl.client.auth=required
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
security.protocol=SSL

#ACL Portion
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
allow.everyone.if.no.acl.found=false
super.users=User:CN=me@me.me
```

I have DEBUG enabled for the authorization logs. If I set the allow.everyone~ to true it works, because it stops worrying about authorization/ACLs I presume and currently the super.users value is being used for my client app and working fine per the DEBUG messages.

As I start the service on each node I get the ClusterAction not permitted when the node look like they are attempting to request UpdateMetadata from one another.

I have applied ACL entry assuming the server CN=server.side

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=10.1.1.5:2181 --add --allow-principal User:CN=server.side  --operation ClusterAction --cluster sample-cluster
```

across all nodes, no dice.

I attempt to set with `--operation ALL` and that didn't work. I also attempt to point the command at the node instead with `--bootstrap-server` and this is failing to return anything at all and I can a timeout error ( I am guessing that it takes the ACL entry but then can't propagate it out to the other nodes because of the above issue).

I have gone through adding ACL for topics, consumers and producers of varied permission scheme but this seems to only occur on start up when the node attempt to cross communicate. As a result I end up with client app consumers and producers that can connect, authorized to their respective topics, but then end up with NO LEADER metadata issues.

I have been on google all day; anyone familiar with this? TIA

Answer (score 0):

According to Confluent documentation at [Authorzation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authorization.html).

> Each broker must be able to communicate with all of the other brokers for replication, and when it acts as the controller. You must add the broker principal as a super user, otherwise Kafka will not work.

Also

> In a secure cluster, both client requests and inter-broker operations require authorization. The inter-broker operations are split into two classes: cluster and topic. Cluster operations refer to operations necessary for the management of the cluster, like updating broker and partition metadata, changing the leader and the set of in-sync replicas of a partition, and triggering a controlled shutdown.

> Because of the way replication of topic partitions works internally, the broker principal must be a super user so that the broker can replicate topics properly from leader to follower.

So, you should add your broker principal(s) to `super.users` list.
BTW, you can configure `ssl.principal.mapping.rules` to extract principal name such that it does not contain the `CN=` part. For example:
a rule like `RULE:^CN=(.*?)$/$1/` will give you a principal like `me@me.me`.